# Why won't my canvas display anything using Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I've copied the code that Fabricjs gives and put it into a file called Fabric.js. I then haave made a file called Canvas.js. I've imported both into my HTML files and am trying to print out a rectangle but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en";>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CustomCase</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="HeaderFooter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SkapaDesign.css">
    <script src="Fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="Canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="Wrapper">  
        <header id="Header"></header>

        <section id="Body">
            <div id="LeftColumn">   
                <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer id="Footer"></footer>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#Body{
    height: 675px;
}
#LeftColumn{
    float: left;
    width: 355px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#Canvas{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('Canvas');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 60,
  height: 70,
  fill: 'red'
});
canvas.add(rect);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're wrapping your code with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

You'll need to include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library in your file as well.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d3RGY/161/